# Is this possible to add Google assistant inside the android application?

Tags: android, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-assistant, google-assist-api

we want to understand how to integrate Google assistant inside android application to listen the voice to navigate to other screen or to do the search on the same activity

We want to integrate the Google Assistant SDK inside android application

Comment: You can add Google Assistant to your experimental projects only.

**You can't launch commercial devices that integrate with the Google Assistant SDK. It's available for experimental and non-commercial uses only.**

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to integrate Google Assistant inside an android application to listen to the voice to navigate to another screen or to do the search on the same activity using the [App Actions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app) . App Actions enable users to say simple voice commands to quickly access Android app’s functionality.